# Show $A \cap (B \cap C) = (A \cap B) \cap C$ Set algebra approach.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show $A \cap (B \cap C) = (A \cap B) \cap C$. Using set algebra approach.

I'm just having trouble convincing myself via the algebraic approach that the statement is true.....I know it is true, I convinced myself visually. But trying to work it out through the algebraic approach is leaving me lacking a solution.

Approach:

1) $A \cap (B \cap C) = (A \cap B) \cap (A \cap C)$

2) $(A \cap B) \cap C = (A \cap C) \cap (B \cap C)$

What I wanted to do was show those two expressions are equivalent....what am I missing to get my conclusion?

Comment: What is the "algebraic approach"?

Comment: @MPW maybe wrong choice of words, what I mean is by using the distributive property.

Comment: @MPW I expect that what is meant is that the OP wishes to prove the associative property of intersection using "algebraic manipulations" using a proof of the form $A\cap (B\cap C)=\cdots = \cdots = (A\cap B)\cap C$ while avoiding direct use of what we want to prove (*or any results that rely on this*) while also (*for whatever ill-conceived reason*) avoiding rewriting things with words such as $(A\cap B)=\{x~:~x\in A~\text{and}~x\in B\}$.

Comment: The easiest proof will however be one that uses words instead of only symbols... and will rely on the fact that the logical *and* is also associative (*something which can be shown using a truth table for instance if not already included as an axiom from the start*).

Comment: @JMoravitz what I gather from your explanation is that I shouldn't over-complicate things by trying to do symbolic manipulation and should in fact use words to explain why the two expressions are equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a bit on how you defined the intersection. But if you defined it as:
$$x\in A\cap B :\iff x\in A \text{ and } y\in B$$

Then you can prove it by using the associative property of the logical "and" which you can show with truth tables.

Assuming this property:

$$ x\in A\cap(B\cap C) \iff x\in A \text{ and } x\in B\cap C\iff\dots$$

Comment: I think this was the assumption I was missing in my construction, because it all seems clear now. Thanks.